# Fundamental misunderstanding of how Angular handles a snippet?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arguments, alert

I'm having a problem debugging some code in an Angular controller. This function is called when a form is submitted on our checkout page. I'm fairly new to Angular, and I'm a bit confused as to what is going on in this function.

```
  $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
    PayStripe.processPayment(status, response).then(
      function(successMessage){
        alert('success', successMessage);
        Order.recordOrder(Cart.cart.items, Auth.user.uid)
          .then(function(){
            PostAffiliatePro.reportSale(Cart.cart.getTotalPrice());
            Cart.cart.clearItems();
            $scope.mode = 'success';
          });
      }
    );
  };
```

Here's what I think is happening line-by-line...

1) We're declaring a function called `handleStripe` with two arguments: `status` and `response`.
2) A method called `processPayment` is being called and is inside of an object dependency injected into the controller called `PayStripe`. `.then` is opened, so the following lines of code will be executed AFTER the `processPayment` method is called.
3) Running an anonymous function with an argument of `successMessage`.
4) I'm  confused as to what's happening here, as I've never seen `alert` called with any arguments other than a message. [this page on `alert`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) is not much help.
5) A method called `recordOrder` is called from the object `Order` which is a dependency of the controller.
6-10) After the `recordOrder` method is called, the cart is cleared, the sale is reported through another method, and the `mode` variable contained in the controller's `scope` is updates to the value `success`.

I've looked through all of the methods associated with these steps, and I still have some questions.

1) Where are all of these arguments being passed in? Are the arguments passed into the functions pre-declared arguments that will be updated by Angular? I.E. are these variables which Angular defines as the process moves through the queue, and whose values are not user-defined? 
2) On line #4, I understand that the second argument is from the argument defined in the function, but what is the combination of these two valued inside the `alert()` function doing?
3) The fix to the bug that comes from this script depends on me being able to change the value of `$scope.mode` to something different as soon as the  `handleStripe` function is called, however I have tried to insert such a declaration in multiple places that seem logical with results varying from the script breaking, to nothing happening at all. To me it seems that the logical place to put `$scope.mode = 'my-value';` would be between current lines #1 and #2, however this produces the affects I mentioned before.

Finally, I feel I may be missing an overall concept, rather than wrestling with syntax. What is this concept called, if I am missing one, and where can I learn to use it?

Comment: For starters...anything with a `then()` means the function returns a promise and `then` is a resolved promise callback. The argument will be whatever the resolve of the promise returns

Comment: How do you know nothing happened when you but the aforementioned line in the aforementioned place?